# How to setup an external firewall to enable Visual Studio remote debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I've read many articles here, at MS and through Google, on remote debugging and all of them cover Windows Firewall and how to open ports and adding the debugger remote agent as an exception. It seems that using the remote debugger it must be able to dynamically open ports.

Using an external firewall, this is not possible. Does anybody know what configuration to use to allow remote debugging through an external firewall? Client computer has all ports open, server has these ports opened:

- TCP 135, 139, 445
- UDP 137, 138, 500, 4500

EDIT: Using Windows 2008 R2 SP1 on the website side and Windows 7 SP1 on the debugging side, where VS is installed. The firewall, however, is external to both and must be configured separately, i.e., it has no info on the running process asking for a port, it just sees the port request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vs2010 managed remote debugging is done via RPC. If your remote OS supports it - you can try to use [configure RPC dynamic port allocation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154596) and open configured ports on your firewall. Btw in addition to ports you also have to configure user access.

Don't know your OS - One more link for more modern operating systems [How to restrict RPC dynamic TCP/IP port allocation](http://watchingthecloud.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-restrict-rpc-dynamic-tcpip-port.html)

```
* NetSh INT IPV4 SET DynamicPort TCP Start=1024 num=65535
* NetSh INT IPV4 SET DynamicPort UDP Start=1024 num=65535
```

Comment: I edited my question to contain info on OS. However, that link looks promising.

Comment: Sorry don't have Windows 2008 to check, but it looks like on 2008 you can set port range simply by NetSH (added in answer). Only be careful, you can get problems with your server if range is too small and opening port range on firewall compromises security to some extent.

Comment: One silly addition (limit open ports on firewall only to your debugging site IP) :)

Comment: That (last thing) was already done, even if I wanted it otherwise, they wouldn't allow me.

Comment: If fact I've thought - you don't even have to reconfigure server. Check current dynamic port range on server with netsh and open that port range on firewall. Hope your FW supports opening ranges :)

Comment: While I'm not yet sure this will work 100% (need to wait before the firewall changes are done) I give it the benefit of the doubt and accept this. But it looks like a viable way, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Visual Studio remote debugging uses DCOM and the problem may be related to:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248809  (that is the issue is probably the NAT, not the firewall).

I would try setting up a VPN and debug through the VPN.  That should work...

Comment: We _have_ a VPN, but since the VPN is to a public server, they still use a firewall (and correctly so, preventing any potential infected and untrusted client to _not_ infect the server).